# what's the best way to include pictures in questions/answers and preserve Exif data?

Tags: feature-request

imgur seems to strip the Exif data when you upload a picture to it using the insert-image icon at the top of the text entry boxes for questions/answers.  Can we switch to a service that doesn't do that, or find a way to use imgur so the Exif data isn't lost, or (a better option that someone else comes up with)?

Comment: +1 Sometimes the pictures posted on answers are just so interestingly done that I ache to see the exif data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its unlikely we will switch from imgur...its used network-wide on StackExchange. I believe they also have their own commercial installation of it, so they have some pretty high end dedicated service for it as well, which is hard to come by for a decent price.

If you need to demonstrate images with full exif, I recommend uploading the full copy to flickr, a smaller version here on imgur, and link the image to the flickr page. People can then view the exif on flickr, and if the flickr copy is ever removed, at least we'll have the imagur copy here.

Comment: Good solution imo

Comment: I'm not really happy about that solution, since it requires using two services.  From googling 'imgur exif data' I get the impression that imgur is pretty adamant about stripping exif data, so I doubt it's something we can change.  You don't have a link (meta post somewhere?) for info about StackExchange's use of imgur, do you?

Comment: @drewbenn: Well, first, there isn't much of a "solution" in terms of changing our image host. Thats not a decision we make, and there are MANY topics on it on meta.stackoverflow.com. Its what we have, its network wide, and I don't believe that will change any time soon simply because we at PhotoSE ask for it to change. Mattdm has a good point about including relevant metadata in the text of each question, however if I understand your point...if you want a reliable source of EXIF data, flickr is the quickest and simplest solution.

Comment: Ah, found the link to the decision to formally use imgur: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94286 . Thanks for the pointer.  And, yes, it sounds like we'll be using imgur for a while.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better if people put the *relevant* metadata in the text of the question. That way, it becomes easily searchable (without resorting to a specialized image search). It would be pretty cool if Stack Exchange provided some nifty automatic way to do that when uploading, though.

Comment: I guess I have two opinions: the first is that it's prone to error, both fat-fingering as well as newbies who will simplify f/2.8 to 1/2, or any other mistake I'm sure we've all seen a dozen times.  The other is that I fear the Exif data will actually start to *poison* results: 1/320, f/4, 200 ISO makes sense in the context of a picture with some brightness and exposure, but by themselves those values are meaningless. Oh, and Exif data can expose (heh) other facts that get left out, like "that's not the camera you said you were using."

Comment: @drewbenn Yeah, automatic extraction of EXIF would be ideal.